# Typical "relation "auth_user" does not exist" with PSQL and Django 2

Tags: python, django, postgresql, migration

**Edit: SOLVED**

I had a line like `creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=User.objects.first().id)` that was the problem.
When I changed it to `creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` all started to work again.

Thanks.

---

I know that it is a recurrent ask, which it's solutioned with migrations, but not my case (I think).

I have a Django project (I've tried with Django 2.0, 2.1 and 2.1.1) that 
had a db.sqlite3 and worked fine. Now, I've tried to switch the database with PostgreSQL 10 with those configurations:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql', #I've already tested with PostgreSQL_psycopg2
        'NAME': 'mydbs',
        'USER': 'niknitro',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

In pg_hba.conf, I added this line:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/32              trust
```

And when I try to do a `python manage.py migrate`, `python manage.py makemigrations` or `python manage.py runserver`, it's the same error:

```
Starting myproject execution...
/root/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
Starting myproject execution...
/root/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f4ce0070e18>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/myproject/WiFiNets/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Wifi(models.Model):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/myproject/WiFiNets/models.py", line 17, in Wifi
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=User.objects.first().id)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 605, in first
    for obj in (self if self.ordered else self.order_by('pk'))[:1]:
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 268, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1186, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1065, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...
```

Also in PostgreSQL.log, appears this line:

```
2018-09-01 14:23:56.064 UTC [22027] niknitro@myproject ERROR:  relation "auth_user" does not exist at character 280
2018-09-01 14:23:56.064 UTC [22027] niknitro@myproject STATEMENT:  SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" ORDER BY "auth_user"."id" ASC  LIMIT 1
```

I know that this error is usually fixed with a makemigrations and a migrate but not this case.
I also tried to remove the migrations but didn't works.

Here are my requirements:

```
amqp==2.3.2
anyjson==0.3.3
billiard==3.5.0.4
celery==4.2.1
certifi==2018.4.16
chardet==3.0.4
Django==2.1.1
django-bootstrap3==9.1.0
django-celery==3.2.2
django-forms-bootstrap==3.1.0
django-rest-framework==0.1.0
django-tables2==1.21.2
djangorestframework==3.8.2
idna==2.7
kombu==4.2.1
psycopg2==2.7.5
psycopg2-binary==2.7.5
pytz==2017.3
requests==2.19.1
urllib3==1.23
vine==1.1.4
```

Please, ask me to share more information if you need it.

Thanks you so much

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py migrate` ??

Comment: Yeh, and a makemigrations, and both returned the same error. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a default that involves a query on the database. That will airways be executed on first import, do the migration that creates the table will never have a chance to run. Remove the default.

Comment: I'm sorry but, which default you means?
Thanks

Comment: The one in the creator field, as mentioned in the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

**Below works for me in Django==4.0.2**

Do the following:

1. Go to **django_migrations** table of your DB and delete all the migrations.(You need to Truncate table)
2. Delete all the migrations file under your **migrations** folder of your Django app.

Then run command:

1. python manage.py makemigrations
2. python manage.py migrate

Answer (score 0):

this error occurs when you connect your Postgre Database to Django.

To solve this issue.

Go to your PGAdmin And delete all Tables related to Django and then apply migrations.

This is how I solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same errors as described in this post, but in my case, the issue was that I was using `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` instead of `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model`. After some investigation, I realized that the cause of the error was related to my **custom User model**, which I had created by subclassing `AbstractUser`. Once I made the change to use `get_user_model()`, the errors were resolved.