# ERROR: relation "auth_user" does not exist at character 280

Tags: django, postgres-9.6

I am trying to deploy my Django application & postgres in Kubernetes.

I am using:-
Django: 2.1.9
Psql: 9.6.3

All the pods and deployment are running successfully in the minikube dashboard. When I try to run the Django deployment service in the browser by entering the superuser credentials, it says wrong username & password. Although I am creating the superuser in the Django web application. The postgres deployment logs give the below error:-
ERROR:  relation "auth_user" does not exist at character 280

I am new to kubernetes and Django. I tried to find a solution online but did not find any fix. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like you need to apply database migrations.

Comment: are you sure your aren't facing something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52129128/typical-relation-auth-user-does-not-exist-with-psql-and-django-2) ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my Kubernetes migration job. The migration commands in the job were not working and therefore I was not able to migrate my Django web app. Then I manually ran the migration command from inside the pod and it worked. Thanks a lot for replies.